# Getting records between 2 values in datediff function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

Could you help me with this please.

I would like to get the records only if the `DATEDIFF(day, due_date, GETDATE())` is **more than 60 but is less than 90 days** (or between 60 days and 90 days). If it is lesser than 60 or greater than 90 days, then leave it out).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @today smalldatetime = getdate()
select 
   due_date
from 
   some_table
where
   datediff(day, due_date, @today) > 60 and
   datediff(day, due_date, @today) < 90
```

Comment: THANKS! I tried it just like that but it didn't work for me. But when I did it your way, IT WORKED! WEIRD!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you (:

Comment: this isn't `sargable`, smalldatetime does not set time to midnight, so may get wrong results (depending on needs and data)

Comment: @Used_By_Already, you wright. But @user3825246 asked about datediff between `due_date` and `getdate()`. So I answered with using just `getdate()` without casting current datetime to today midnight.

Comment: @Indian I am more concerned about the use of functions on the data (i.e. a not sargable approach) - even if asked for that, it is better to provide the best way that you know. If the asker knew it already they would not ask.

Answer (score 2):

a sargable alternative =>> it does not use functions on the data

```
-- DECLARE @today datetime = CAST(GETDATE() AS date) -- an option

DECLARE @today datetime = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT
      due_date
FROM some_table
WHERE (
          due_date >= DATEDIFF(DAY, -90, @today)
      AND due_date <  DATEDIFF(DAY, -60, @today)
      )
```

GETDATE() returns both date and the current time, so to get "today" at 00:00:00 you need to either cast getdate to a date, or use the dateadd function as shown above.

Then instead of calculating the days different for each row of data (2 functions for each row) and filtering on that calculated column (this could require hundreds, thousands or millions of calculations), why not compare the existing data to 2 calculated dates?

<kbd>[See: Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)</kbd>